# multiple dropdown lists validation using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have five (5) individual dropdown lists on my web page.

1. cities
2. iptypes
3. purposes
4. billings
5. protocols

I want to validate that user must have at-least to select any one [ drop down list ] of them [ from 5 dropdowns ] to proceed next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your drop downs has class called mySelects,

```
if ($('.mySelects option:selected').length == 0)
{
  // no drop-down has selected
}
```

Comment: VinayC: would that not fail when each select has a "Please select" option?

Comment: @mplungjan, yes, if you are using option such as "Please select" or "--Select" then this code won't work. In such case, you have to loop through each dropdown.

Comment: Cant you use selectedIndex>0 on each?

Comment: @mplungjan, yes but as said that would require iterating over each drop-down such as `$('.mySelects option:selected').each(function() { ...'`. Now, in that iterator function, I can either use selected index or actual selected text.

Answer (score 1):

Make a mutual exclusive validation easily by [Ketchup plugin](http://demos.usejquery.com/ketchup-plugin/).

You can see the sample in demo for `CheckBox`es.

Or you can assign them the same name and select their selected options and check it's length, like what the VinayC did and then show a message.

Comment: You're welcome dude, so try to Mark one of the replies as answer(not necessarily mine) if it solved your issue :-)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit='return checkvalue();'>
    <p><label for='cities'>City: </label>
    <select id='cities' name='cities' >
       <option value=''>Please select city</option>
       <option value='city1'>City 1</option>
       <option value='city2'>City 2</option>
       <option value='.....'>.....</option>
    </select>
    </p>

    <p><label for='iptypes'>IP Types: </label>
    <select id='iptypes' name='iptypes' >
       <option value=''>Please IP Type</option>
       <option value='type1'>Type 1</option>
       <option value='type2'>Type 2</option>
       <option value='.....'>.....</option>
    </select>
    </p>

    <p><label for='purposes'>Purposes: </label>
    <select id='purposes' name='purposes' >
       <option value=''>Please select Purpose</option>
       <option value='purpose1'>Purpose 1</option>
       <option value='purpose2'>Purpose 2</option>
       <option value='.....'>.....</option>
    </select>
    </p>

    <p><label for='billings'>Billing: </label>
    <select id='billings' name='billings' >
       <option value=''>Please select billing</option>
       <option value='billing1'>Billing 1</option>
       <option value='billing2'>Billing 2</option>
       <option value='.....'>.....</option>
    </select>
    </p>

    <p><label for='protocols'>Protocols: </label>
    <select id='protocols' name='protocols' >
       <option value=''>Please select protocol</option>
       <option value='protocol1'>Protocol 1</option>
       <option value='protocol2'>Protocol 2</option>
       <option value='.....'>.....</option>
    </select>
    </p>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function checkvalue() {
        if(document.getElementById('cities').value !== '' ||
           document.getElementById('iptypes').value !== '' ||
           document.getElementById('purposes').value !== '' ||
           document.getElementById('billings').value !== '' ||
           document.getElementById('protocols').value !== ''
          )
    {
       return true;
    }

    alert('Please select at least one value');
    return false;
}
```